# If I use dropout in a neural network and run it for a large number of steps, do I risk deleting all the units?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, dropout

I'm still trying to understand dropout completely, but this is what think is happening so far:

1. At each step there is a chance *p* of a unit being set to zero.
2. If a rectified linear unit (ReLU) is used for activation, then a weight of zero can often result in 'dead' units.
3. If I run a network for a long time (i.e. towards infinity), will all my units become stuck at zero?

I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure why or what process is involved.

Comment: No, If you think of what goes one in your own brain, some thoughts are just not worth having. So too with neural nets.

Comment: `a weight of zero can often result in 'dead' units.`  No, a dead node is when the input weights (and bias) are such that the *output* is always zero.  Those input weights are not zero for this to happen, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're conflating the dead ReLU problem and dropout. ReLU nets often use dropout, but they are not the same.

**Dropout**

Using dropout "freezes" some units (at random and usually but not always independently) by ignoring their weights at each iteration. The frozen units are not *set* to zero, but for that iteration, the network *pretends* that they are zero. The frozen units are not updated for this iteration.

For the next iteration, **all** units, including the ones that were frozen during the last iteration, are available to be frozen (again, at random). It's possible for some units to be frozen several times in a row (albeit with diminishing probability).

The non-frozen units are evaluated and updated as usual.

You can use dropout with any type of neuron.

**Dead ReLU**

So-called "dead neurons" or "dead ReLUs" happen when the weights update in such a way that the unit always returns 0 for any of the inputs in the data set; for example, if the inputs are between 0 and 1, but the weight is negative, then the ReLU always returns 0. Once this happens, the back-propagation can't update the unit: because it's output is always 0, so is its gradient, and the weight never changes. ELUs and other variations on ReLU can ameliorate this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still a bit confused though. 

When we say "set a unit to zero" i.e. dropout, does that not mean that the output will be zero and hence the gradient will be zero?

Comment: Are they only skipped, i.e. weights and output remain the same for two iterations in a row? Or is the weight or output set to 0 and also skipped for one iteration?

Comment: Thank you, now I think I get it. I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking, if one keeps the learning rate not too high, empirically units tend not to be hard-dead: there will still be at least a few data points with a gradient that 'saves' them. Whether that means if you trained to infinity, on a small enough learning rate, are you guaranteed they would / wouldnt all die, I'm not sure. I suppose Gaussians have mass even out to infinity, so it's hard to say for sure that the nodes will never die. But in practice, they dont, under small enough learning rates, for some not-very-rigorous definition of 'small enough'.